# gridview and if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a gridview control, and a button which visible had been set to false. Supposedly when I select a particular row on the gridview, it will set the visible of the button to true.

However now the problem is, despite setting the if statement at the code behind, the button still remain visible to false.

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label certify = (Label)GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("certify");
    Label Status = (Label)GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("Status");

    if ((certify.ToString() == "True") & (Status.ToString() == "Not Paid"))
    {
        paymentbtn.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

When I debug the program, i managed the get data from the gridview. certify was set to True and Status was set to Not Paid. However, the code still skip the if statement.. which I have no idea why is it so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Text` property of `label` instead of calling ToString() of label to get value.

*Change*

```
if ((certify.ToString() == "True") & (Status.ToString() == "Not Paid"))
{
    paymentbtn.Visible = true;
}
```

*To*

```
if ((certify.Text == "True") & (Status.Text  == "Not Paid"))
{
    paymentbtn.Visible = true;
}
```